# Netbeans 7.2 not starting

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.2

I recently installed Netbeans 7.2 beta and it worked fine. Then I installed Netbeans 7.2 final release on top of beta and during the installation, Netbeans 7.1 and Netbeans 7.12 were there. Now when I launch Netbeans, it does not go beyond "loading modules" stage. Simply the Netbeans screen disappear few seconds after the launch. Then I did the following.

- Uninstalled all the Netbeans versions and re-installed Netbeans 7.2
- Deleted AppData/Netbeans folder
- Deleted User/.nbi folder
- Searched the registry and deleted Netbeans related entries. (But only one entry was found)
- Deleted Netbeans Folder in Program Files folder.
- Uninstalled and Re-installed in a separate drive.
- Uninstalled and Re-installed under another user account.

None of the above worked, the only thing I did not try was to re-install the Windows XP operating system.

It there any option to try before re-installing the operating system?

Comment: same thing happened to me ( netbeans would disappear). while I was searching for the solutions , it started ( after few minutes ) . Strange !!!

Comment: This is might be posted in superuser..

Comment: I had the same problem... turns out i configured the wrong version of JDK during the instalation process.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was having the same problem .... with netbeans 7.2 ,go to user/appdata/roaming/7.2/modules/ and delete all the jar files except docs,ext,locale folders ... and start the ide again... basically the problem betides when u update the ide after update when u start the ide it stuck to the loading module phase.

Comment: i had problem, but i deleted .git folder in project and IDE did not start

so, i deleted only GIT module from C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3\modules

Comment: +1 Nice! this happened with me in ubuntu & windows both, several times but no fix worked as this one did.

Comment: This solution worked, but it seems like I need to reinstall all my plugins?

Comment: I can't see `modules` directory under C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2, but `config` and `var` :(

Comment: got the same issue with NB 8.1 ... your solution just saved me :)

Comment: @Miron, did you manage to sort the issue out? I'm on Netbeans 7.3 and as your case, I can just see `config` and `var` under that directory, there's no `modules` folder

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to check proper version of JDK is installed.
Netbeans 7.2 requires JDK 1.7, not 1.8.
You can check {Netbeans Install Path}/etc/netbeans.conf. There find `netbeans_jdkhome` and its value. Make sure you install JDK1.7 and this line `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25"` for example.
If not, change the value to proper installation path.

Answer (score 2):

That's some stability issue with NetBeans 7.2

Just Kill and Restart the IDE and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that right JDK directory chosen in the installation wizard if you not sure you can change it from
`C:\Program Files\NetBeans {netbeans version}\etc`
you will see a file which is
`netbeans.conf`
edit it(I am using Notepad++ for that)
At the bottom of the file, you will see a line
`netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\{jdk directory you want}"`
make sure it is valid JDK and it is JDK, not JRE

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, make sure you have the required JDK version configured during the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

First tried everything to no avail, finally I had to uninstall NetBeans 7, then install NetBeans 8, which also aligned with my JDK 8. This resolved the issue for me. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, finally this worked with me on version 11.3, delete this folder, then run the program again

```
C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans
```

here my main username is Dell, yours can be different ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

I found out in my Windows installation of Apache Netbeans 12.4, the file 'tctracker.properties' in 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.4\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\core\windows' was filled with null values. I fixed the issue with letting netbeans generate a new file by moving this '12.4' directory to somewhere else on the disk, starting Netbeans, letting it generate a new 'tctracker.properties'-file, stop it, replace the corrupt file in with this newly generated file and put the '12.4' directory back in place.