# NetBeans IDE 7.2 does not start

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.2

Previous to installing the latest version of the NetBeans IDE 7.2 I uninstalled my previous version. The ide does not start. I see the hour glass for a few seconds in my Windows Vista and disappears and nothing happens. I am left with no IDE to run. Your help is most appreciated. Rifai

Answer (score 0):

What Bundle of Netbeans did you download?

- Download "*OS independend ZIP*" (at Platform) unzip and run it, does it work?
- Did you change something in config files (**`Netbeans 7.2/etc/`**)
- Take a look at NB Logfiles (**`<user>/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/var/log`**) - any warnings / errors?
- Check if there are some settings left (**`<user>/AppData/Local/NetBeans`** and **`<user>/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans`**)? If yes delete them (backup if required)
- Is there any error message or dialog?

---

**Edit:**

Next thing you can try:

Go to your **`etc`** folder of Netbeans and open the file **`netbeans.conf`** (you need a better editor than notepad since the file has unix-linebreaks). Look for those two settings:

- `netbeans_default_userdir="${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT}/7.2"`
- `netbeans_default_cachedir="${DEFAULT_CACHEDIR_ROOT}/7.2"`

Change both paths to something else like **`"${HOME}/userdir"`** / **`"${HOME}/cache"`** - but make shure you dont use one folder for both (see comments above the settings).

Now start Netbeans and check if both folders are created and contain some files. I guess with **`${HOME}`** both are created in the **`bin`**.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here are the answers to your questions: 1. I downloaded NetBeans 7.2.1 windows installer. 2. I have not changed any config files. I checked the file but made no changes. 3. I have no log files in the <user>/AppData/Roaming/ the directory does not exist. 4. I see no error messages only an hour glass for a few seconds and no starting of the IDE.

Comment: I see ... does the whole Roaming direcory not exist or only the Netbeans one? Btw. the next step you can try is too long for comments so i'll edit it into my post.

Comment: Sorry I meant <user>/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans. I am still waiting for the next step. I checked your post at StackOverflow. Could not find any.

Comment: Se my post here, after `Edit:` (with `userdir` etc.) did this work?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169565/netbeans-7-2-not-starting/36628682#36628682) may help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on windows 10 and Netbeans 7.2.1

Open Task Manager --> Go to Users Tab --> Look for Netbeans IDE, if found, select and then click on End Task.

Open Netbeans again, hopefully, will start.