# Netbeans suddenly failed to start after saying "Done Loading modules"

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.4, netbeans-8

Netbeans 8.0 fails to start in Ubuntu 12.04 suddenly. Previously it used to work fine. But now it does not start, when I try to start, the netbeans blue loading box shows up, sometime after showing the message "Done Loading modules", it disappears & netbeans windows does not appear. However netbeans is still shown in the running processes, but the netbeans windows does not open after any time.

In the past, this also happened with netbeans 7.4 sometime ago when I disabled some plugins (probably it was due to disabling some Hudson plugin/Husdon UI plugin). But now this time it is  probably after an automatic update of a plugin, I don't know which one now. I tried remove the entire cache directory as well but no improvement to situation. Is reinstalling netbeans, the only solution each time(Huh!) ?

## Edit:

Sometimes it works when I run from terminal using(worked for netbeans 8.0 but not for 7.4):

```
$ /bin/sh  /home/user/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans
```

Comment: For others who stuck at this: here's the fix http://stackoverflow.com/a/13774654/530153

Comment: ```Shell ~/.netbeans$ tail -f -n 150 ./8.2/var/log/messages.log ```
 revealed the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced this before with Netbeans 7.4 and 8 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and on Windows 7 SP1 x64. The only way I could solve it was by removing Netbeans and its [cache](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir), and then reinstalling it. Maybe it's a rigorous solution, but it's a solution.

However, maybe you can check your logs and see if there is an exception somewhere. It could be helpful to at least report an issue to the Netbeans developers (or plugin developers, if a plugin is the culprit), so your particular issue (and possibly mine) can be fixed. Off the top of my head, the Netbeans startup log for Ubuntu is located at `/home/<user>/.netbeans/8/var/log`, you could check that out.

Another way to go is to reinstall Netbeans and add your plugins one by one. That way you can root out the culprit and address its developers.