# I can not open Netbeans. It is stuck in 'initializing modules'. What is happening?

Tags: netbeans, ide

I tried to open Netbeans but during initialization the IDE doesn't load.
It gets stuck in this step: 'Initializing Modules'.

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled, and exclude same cache files, but I still have the same problem.

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.0., Windows 8.1, Java jdk 1.7.0_25.
I haven't tried on other configurations, Netbeans was working fine until today.

Comment: Insufficient information to offer an answer, sorry.

Comment: @mingos Tell me what else do you need?

Comment: Start with your OS + version, Java version, whether the same happens on other configurations and with other NB versions, other potentially conflicting software installed/running. My guess is that the issue too localised (it happens specifically in your hardware + software environment). I wouldn't expect an answer.

Comment: are you already try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819991/netbeans-suddenly-failed-to-start-after-saying-done-loading-modules ?

Comment: I have found that if I rename c:\users\hslafo\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\ to c:\users\hslafo\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans_old and start with a new area here this resolves without having to un-install and reinstall (maybe a heavy handed approach)